# how to create button with two function save and displaying or print in pdf in laravel

Tags: laravel, pdf

i'd like to create button to:

1. saving the transaction.
2. print the transaction

how to do this using button in laravel. below is the transaction page 
[image: Button with two function saving and printing the receipt]

this is my code to saving the transaction

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $detailtrans = new DetailTrans;
        $detailtrans->cde_detailtrans = $request->cde_detailtrans;
        $detailtrans->cde_customer = $request->cde_customer;
        $detailtrans->cde_layanan = $request->cde_services;
        $detailtrans->weight_laundry = $request->weight_laundry;
        $detailtrans->tot_charge = $request->tot_charge;
        $detailtrans->id = Auth::user()->id;
        $detailtrans->save();

        return Redirect::Route('detailtrans.create');
    }
```

above code work fine to saving the transaction, but i do not know how to write code to print the transaction receipt.

Comment: Do you want to generate a transaction pdf and print that 1? Could you be a bit more specific?.

Comment: yes i want to generate a transaction pdf called receipt to print currenct transaction

Comment: You could use DomPDF the create the pdf and uset the fuction stream to output the generated pdf. If you show the pdf the user will have the option to print. Otherwise you could redirect to a view and use javascript window.print() to print the view.

Comment: @mogleng Do you generate pdf file or do you want to print Html view?

Comment: @GörkemD.i'd prefer html view...yes html view

Answer (score 1):

you could just pass it to a view and show it with table or something and add a print button under that like this:

```
<div style="text-align:center">
    <button onclick="window.print();">print</button>
</div>
```

this js code `onclick="window.print();"` prints the page to everything user wants.

Comment: works normal i add this in the store function in the DetailTransController

    $lastRecord = DB::table('tbl_detailtrans')->orderBy('cde_detiltrans', 'DESC')->first();
    
            return view('detailtrans.show', ['lastRecord'=>$lastRecord]);

and display the variable in blade view by this

     {{ $lastRecord->cde_detailtrans}}